# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar 2 digitos en una palabra con expresiones regulares?

Tags: regex

Estoy intentando matchear 2 o más digitos en una palabra. Hasta ahora he podido detectar dos dígitos consecutivos de esta forma "\d{2,}" o "[0-9]{2,}", pero solo sirve para por ejemplo: "Prueba12", "34Prueba", pero no sirve para "1Prueba5", "Pru3e9ba"
[Prueba en Regexr](https://regexr.com/5ucpb)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes encontrar solamente 2? O pueden ser más?
Si son 2 entonces el regex seria `(\D*\d+){2,}`.

Saludos.-

Comment: Hola Juan, pueden ser 2 o más. Gracias!

Comment: No me deja darte puntos, funciona perfecto para 2 o más digitos. Muchas gracias!.

Comment: Para hacerlo un poco más eficiente, debería estar anclado al inicio del texto `^(?:\D*\d){2}`, así evita probar múltiples veces cuando no encuentra. Además, si sólo es para obtener un resultado verdadero/falso, no es necesario `{2,}` (2 o más), si coincide con 2 alcanza y sobra